# How to send sql command containing a variable without running a console

Tags: mysql

I use the following mysql command to rename contents in video table, path column

```
UPDATE video
SET path = INSERT(path, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2, 0, '201410110');
```

But ideally i want 201410110 to be replaced with a $mask variable that will be stored in a script that i am building

```
mask=$(date +%s)
mysql -u videditor -pPassword1 "UPDATE master.video SET path = INSERT(path, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2, 0, '$mask');"
```

But I get an error when I try to run the sql command. Any clue what I am missing?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First export the variable. Then you have to set the `database` and use `-e` before the query.

```
export mask=$(date +%s)
mysql -u videditor -pPassword1 <database> -e "UPDATE master.video SET path = INSERT(path, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2, 0, '$mask');"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable with  `SET` statemnt, like this.

```
SET @mask = '201410110';
UPDATE video SET path = INSERT(path, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2, 0, @mask);
```

You can read more on `SET` at [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html)

Comment: so in my case it would be SET @mark = 'date +%s' if i wanted to use epoch time for variable?

Comment: i never used it for string building like you need, so you should probably go with `@jherran` answer